# Java gives me OutofBounds error but I can still print the array?

Tags: java, list, bufferedreader

I'm using .substring to read a specific part of a string from a text file. Here's a sample of the string to be read:

2093505,"AMBROS, RALPH HENRY B",BS Entrep 1,M,23,93.94

We're supposed to ignore the quotes, which is why I'm using substring. When I run the program though, I get this error:

````
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at edu.slu.prog2.finals2.VidezStudentsRecords.readDataFileIntoList(VidezStudentsRecords.java:54)
    at edu.slu.prog2.finals2.VidezStudentsRecords.run(VidezStudentsRecords.java:29)
    at edu.slu.prog2.finals2.VidezStudentsRecords.main(VidezStudentsRecords.java:21)```
````

This is the code where the error is:

```
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader buffy = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (filename));
            while(true){
                String line = buffy.readLine();
                if(line == null){
                    break;
                }
              String[] studentData = line.split(",");
                System.out.println(studentData[0]);
                String id = studentData[0];
                String lastName = studentData[1].substring(1);
                String firstName = studentData[2].substring(1, studentData[2].length() - 1);
                String program = studentData[3].substring(0, studentData[3].length() - 2);
                byte year = Byte.parseByte(studentData[3].charAt(studentData[3].length() - 1) + "");
                char gender = studentData[4].charAt(0);
                int age = Integer.parseInt(studentData[5]);
                double average = Double.parseDouble(studentData[6]);

                //System.out.println(id + " ");
                //System.out.print(lastName + " " + firstName + " " + program + " " + year + " " + gender + " " + age + " " + average);


               Student student = new Student(id, lastName, firstName, program, year, gender, age, average);
               students.add(student);
            }
            buffy.close();
            return students;
        }
```

I can print the details just fine. They show up in order and everything, but it still gives me the OutofBounds error for all of the details (id, name, year, etc). Where am I going wrong?

Sample output:

```
2093505 AMBROS RALPH HENRY B BS Entrep 1 M 23 93.94
2091931 BALIAGA ALEJANDRO A BS Entrep 1 M 18 81.11
2093231 BALTAZAR JEROME S BS Entrep 1 M 22 69.37
```

Comment: Whats written at `VidezStudentsRecords.java:54`? What do you mean by you can print the data fine although it throws? Are you possibly catching the exception? Otherwise your code can not continue and will end the program once the exception happens.

Comment: Is the above code for VidezStudentsRecords.java? Which is line 54?

Comment: Yes, the code is for VidezStudentRecords.java, and this is line 54:  String lastName = studentData[1].substring(1);

Comment: Hi, it used to have a try-catch loop, that's how I found the error in the first place. By printing the data fine, I mean that every part of the data is in its right place and that it was read fine, but it's still giving me the outofbounds error...

Comment: BTW, with *2093505,"AMBROS, RALPH HENRY B",BS Entrep 1,M,23,93.94* it has embedded commas (within "...,...") so you would better off using a proper csvReader

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I've never used csvReader before though, do you have any guides that would help?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/

Comment: This debug issue is not reproducible for the sample data you provided.  Please read the post [how create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You should have used `try/catch` block and in the `catch` then print the input line which cause this issue

Comment: @GRAEVENYURIVIDEZ You can remove double quotes by `replaceAll("\"","")`, so there will be no " and you won't have to use `.substring(1)`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occurring because you're only splitting the string by "," so every space that follows each comma is registered as a separate string in studentData. To fix this, you can use a regular expression like so:

```
String[] studentData = line.split(", (\")?");
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but the error still occurs. Thanks again for that splitting technique though, I'll keep that in mind from now on

Comment: Sorry, try this instead String[] studentData = line.split(",(\")?"); I accidentally added the space in there.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use the split code (\",\"|\",|,\"|,).